# Trying to pause whilst running mplayer from webserver

Tags: mplayer

Hi i am creating my own user interface using python.
In this i currently run mplayer from a click with nohup (so as not to mess up the server running), what i would like to do is add a pause button.

Is this possible when running nohup or is there a better way to do it?

so trying

```
os.system("nohup mplayer file.mp3 &")
```

does not allow a pause as far as i could find.

then;

```
os.system("rm /tmp/mplayer")
os.system("mkfifo /tmp/mplayer")
os.system("nohup mplayer -slave -input file=/tmp/mplayer file.mp3 &")
```

My pause button is then created using;

```
os.system("echo pause > /tmp/mplayer") ##click again to unplay
```

works if typed in new terminal but kills my webserver whilst playing. So does not work from webserver.

Currently working with Flask/Python and jinja templates.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason why you are not using the [python-mplayer](http://code.google.com/p/python-mplayer/) wrapper to control mplayer from python? This module is pretty complete and gives you control over the playback functions including pausing.

EDIT:
for non-standard mplayer binary location introspection method may need to be called (based on [wiki entry from official page](http://code.google.com/p/python-mplayer/wiki/Introspection).

```
from mplayer import Player

# First, specify the correct path to the MPlayer executable
Player.exec_path = '/actual/path/to/the/mplayer-bin'

# Then, manually call the introspect() class method
Player.introspect()


# Since autospawn is True by default, no need to call player.spawn() manually
player = Player()

# Play a file
player.loadfile('/path/to/file.mkv')

# Pause playback
player.pause()
```

Comment: I have never seen this before, sounds perfect but struggling to get it working (the documentation seems somewhat lacking).

Comment: I have never used it on linux however should have some examples for windows if your are interested.

Comment: would be great, my biggest issue is how to merge it with my existing project. ie where to drop mplayer folder etc so i can import it into my scripts.

Comment: you can put the executable wherever you want just set the `exec_path` class property to point to the executable before instantiating the player object. Have a look here: http://code.google.com/p/python-mplayer/wiki/Player and modify the exec_path the same way cmd_prefix is modified in the example. By default the wrapper searches for the executable in the working directory if I remember right.

Comment: I thought i was getting my head round python but this has me stumped. In linux you simple type 'mplayer file.mp3' to play it. So struggling, will keep going though because if i can make this work it should make the rest easier. Cheers

Comment: you may need to call `introspect()` method if mplayer binary is somewhere else than default for the module.